# Laravel API call return 403 instead of 422

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

something really simple this morning and I bug on it...

I created a post route in `routes/api.php`

```
Route::post ('/newsletter', NewsletterController::class)->name('api.newsletter');
```

My controller is a single method controller

```
public function __invoke(NewsletterRequest $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'message' => [
            'fr' => 'Merci de vous être inscrits à notre infolettre.',
            'en' => 'Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter.',
        ],
        'data' => $request->validated(),
    ]);
}
```

From what I read here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validation-error-response-format if the validator fail it should automatically return a JSON with the error and a status 422 but I get an 403...

Here's my validator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class NewsletterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }

    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any idea what I've done wrong ?

P.S. I'm not using any Policies for now, I should not be blocked.

Comment: Everything looks correct here. Maybe there's something else forbidding your request? You can double-check the progress by adding `Log::info(__CLASS__.':'.__FUNCTION);` in each function of both your form request and invoke method, then check your log in `storage/logs` to see if it hit any of those functions.

Comment: So I added it in rules, authorize and the invoke and I never get the invoke log, it means that it was stopped by the rules as intended, but it return the wrong error... I did'nt receive any error message just a 403 :/ 

[2022-10-20 14:11:02] local.INFO: App\Http\Requests\NewsletterRequest:authorize  
[2022-10-20 14:11:02] local.INFO: App\Http\Requests\NewsletterRequest:rules

Comment: Using a FormRequest injection will send the request back immediately if it fails, and it will never hit the controller. If you want to change the default messages, you can create a messages function and add them in. If you want to modify the response entirely, then add the validation into the function instead of using a FormRequest

Comment: It is interesting that it's returning a 403 Forbidden instead of a 422, which [is the default status](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#creating-form-requests). 403 is normally thrown if authorize is set to false, but that's not the case here. So maybe something else is giving the Forbidden message?

Comment: I was able to make it work with a validator inside the method, but i'm trying to keep the code where it belongs and it's stated in the doc that it's not the attended behavior to send back a 403. Maybe I should fill a bug at laravel ?

Comment: To answer your previous question, it's almost impossible it's something else, that's a new project that i'm the only one to code in it and there's no gates / policies / middleware installed yet...